# JQuery-like single / multi container class in Java

Tags: java, jquery, design-patterns, java-8, completable-future

I'm looking to implement some sort of `jQuery`-like object in [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) which, acting as container, can contain **one** or **more** objects.

In `Jquery` you can e.g do: `$('.bla').addClass('ble');`. It is unknown whether this is applied on one or more objects, yet the method is only one.

I was also very surprised to see that in `java-8` you can do `CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture<?>... cfs).join()`.

No matter how many objects you pass, you will get a single `CompletableFuture<Void>` and you can call any instance method that will act on all internal objects.

Still, [its](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#CompletableFuture.allOf%28java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture%5B%5D%29) implementation is definitely too complex for my case.

My base `interface` looks like this

```
public interface Response< T extends DataTransferObject< ? > > {

    // instance methods

    public boolean isSuccess();
    public String getMessage();

    public default boolean isUndefined() {
        return this.equals(ActionResponse.UNDEF);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public default Response< T > mergeWith(final Response< ? super T > response) {
        return Response.allOf(this, response);
    }

    public default boolean isMultiResponse() {
        return this instanceof ActionResponse.ActionMultiResponse;
    }
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    // factory methods

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static < U extends DataTransferObject< ? > > Response< U > allOf(final Response< ? super U >... responses) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(responses);

        if (responses.length == 0) return ( Response< U > ) ActionResponse.UNDEF;

        return new ActionResponse.ActionMultiResponse< U >(responses);
    }

    public static < U extends DataTransferObject< ? > > Response< U > from(final boolean success, final String message) {
        return new ActionResponse<>(success, message);
    }
}
```

The `package-protected class` looks like this (incomplete):

```
/* Package-protected implementation for the Response< T > type */
class ActionResponse< T extends DataTransferObject< ? > > implements Response< T > {

    static final Response< ? extends DataTransferObject< ? > > UNDEF = new ActionResponse<>();

    private final boolean success;
    private final String message;

    private ActionResponse() {
        this.success = false;
        this.message = null;
    }

    ActionResponse(final boolean success, final String message) {
        this.success = success;
        this.message = message;
    }

    // getters

    static final class ActionMultiResponse< T extends DataTransferObject< ? > > extends ActionResponse< T > {

        private final String[] messages;

        ActionMultiResponse(final boolean success, final String message) {
            super(success, message);
            this.messages = null;
        }

        ActionMultiResponse(final Response< ? super T >... responses) {

            /* must check if any of the following is already a MultiActionResponse */
            // TODO

            this.messages = new String[responses.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
                this.messages[i] = responses[i].getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getMessage() {

            if (this.messages == null) return super.getMessage();

            return Arrays.toString(this.messages); // dummy string merger
        }
    }
}
```

It's important that classes outside of this `package` can access only the `interface` as I want the implementation details to be hidden. Nobody should care on whether a given instance is a `single` or a `multi`.

The only way you can build a `Response< T >` would be via the factory methods provided or the instance method `Response::mergeWith`. E.g:

```
Response< SpotDTO > response = Response.from(true, "message");
```

---

If was wondering if this is indeed a `pattern` and if such `pattern` has a name? If so, what guidelines should I follow?

What is a better way to implement this `concept`?

For instance, I do not like that the `ActionResponse` holds a `String` type for `message` whereas `ActionMultiResponse` has `String[]`.

Still I do not want to have only one object with a `String` array and place if needed only one object inside.

Comment: You broke the spell when you did `return new ActionResponse.ActionMultiResponse< U >(responses);`. What you should have done here is to continue with using the static factory methods, so something like `ActionResponse.from(responses)`, this method will then choose to either create a multi-response or a single, but the return type will still be `ActionResponse` or even `Response`. Also when you have something like `isMultiResponse`, you are exposing internal details. The user does not need to know this

Comment: @smac89 agree with the first. the latter was just a left-over utility